# How can I handle with BottomNavBar in Compose + Fragment Navigation?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-navigation

I am using compose on UI. And my navigation is native, not compose.

How can I use Fragments as content of Scaffold in this situation ?

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun HomeScreen() {
    Scaffold(bottomBar = { BottomNavBar() }) {
        // --> Content as fragment to here.
    }
}

@Composable
fun BottomNavBar() {
    var selectedItem by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val bottomNavItems = listOf(
        BottomNavItem(name = "First Fragment"),
        BottomNavItem(name = "Second Fragment")
    )
    NavigationBar {
        bottomNavItems.forEachIndexed { index, bottomNavItem ->
            NavigationBarItem(
                selected = selectedItem == index,
                onClick = { selectedItem = index },
                label = { Text(bottomNavItem.name) }
            )
        }
    }
}
```